# How do I fill two different columns with list values by position via odds and even criteria

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rbind

I want to create a data frame from a list that contains this kind of data:

```
names_values <- list("Name1", 22, "Name2", 18, "Name3", 10, "Name4", 16)
```

See that 22 is the complement of "Name1", 18 is the complement of "Name2" and 10 is the complement of "Name3". If I wish to convert this list in a data frame, the output must display a 4 by 2 data frame. The way I think it is going to work is to put the evens in the first column and the odds in the second. I created the following script:

```
library(dplyr)

names_values <- list("Name1", 22, "Name2", 18, "Name3", 10)

even <- function(x){
  x %% 2 == 0
}

odd <- function(x){
  x %% 2 != 0
}

pileUp <- function(names_values){
  temp <- data.frame()
  df <- data.frame()
  for(i in 1:length(names_values)){
    if(even(i)){
      temp$names <- names_values[i]
    }
    else if(odd(i)){
      temp$values <- names_values[i]
    }
    df <- rbind(df, temp)
  }
}

pileUp(names_values)
```

The result I get is this:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "values", value = list("Name1")) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

What should I do? Maybe `rbindlist` instead of `rbind`? I believe that the algorithm logic is also defective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a two line base R method that could be accomplished in one line.

```
# get vector of positions
pos <- seq_along(names_values)
# use vector as logical with modulus 2 (%% 2) to index properly
data.frame(name=unlist(names_values[as.logical(pos %% 2)]),
           vals=unlist(names_values[!(pos %% 2)]))
   name vals
1 Name1   22
2 Name2   18
3 Name3   10
4 Name4   16
```

Answer (score 1):

Split into tuples belonging on each row with `split`, then bind tuples with `rbindlist` or similar:

```
s = split(names_values, rep(1:4, each=2))
data.table::rbindlist(s)

      V1 V2
1: Name1 22
2: Name2 18
3: Name3 10
4: Name4 16
```

Or in base...

```
setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, s), c("Name", "Value"))

   Name Value
1 Name1    22
2 Name2    18
3 Name3    10
4 Name4    16
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just use subsetting on your original list, after turning it into a vector:

```
#turn from list into vector
names_values <- unlist(names_values)

#subset odd
names <- names_values[seq(1,length(names_values),2)]

#subset even
numbers <- names_values[seq(2,length(names_values),2)]

#turn into dataframe

data <- data.frame(names = names, numbers = numbers)
```

Comment: `data$numbers` is a factor variable, but should probably be numeric. Instead of `unlist` up front, you could do `unlist(L[subset])` and preserve type, I think. A pain to test since your code overwrote the input...